# A linux distro to use inside an existing environment

Tags: linux, unix

At work i am forced to use an old version RedHat enterprise. This is okay for most purposes, but there are some applications where I *really* want to use a newer version (vim, ctag, git, tmux, etc...).

As I am not root on the system, I have overcome this problem by creating a "myroot" folder, where i have installed all the application and libraries I need. To activate those I set the PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_PATH ( and others) environment variables.

This is working fine, and my system administrator is happy with the solution (it does not course extra work for him). The problem is that I want more and more demanding applications with more dependencies, which make this solution hard to maintain.

The system is build around a set of shell scripts, but I am considering to convert it to bitbake files.

My question is now if there exists an existing tool/distro which allready fits my needs.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask your sysadmin to install you a `chroot`-ed environment. However, newer libc might not work very well with very old kernels.

Comment: I could do that, or I could just use an virtual machine, but both of these approaches will not allow me to use all the existing applications which I also needs. I want an add-on layer which are as thin as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [pkgsrc](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html). It does pretty much exactly what you've been doing, but will manage dependencies for you.

(Also look at http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/faq.html#non-root-pkgsrc)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `pkgsrc` that Kristof recommended is the [Nix](http://nixos.org/nix/) package manager. It builds and installs packages in a purely functional manner -- each user gets an isolated environment containing only packages they select, and different versions of packages and their dependencies are isolated from each other, so you're guaranteed that an update does not break existing software.

There is currently no pre-built version for RHEL, but I'm working on updating the upstream spec file, and will submit it to Fedora and the EPEL repository for RHEL in the next couple of weeks. Which RHEL version are you using, so I can be sure to make it available there?

Comment: Wow, this looks like a really cool project. I will definitely have a look at this. I'm using RHEL 5, but I will properly just download the source and compile it. However, for this specific purpose, I will start out by testing pgksrc

Comment: Yes, at this moment it's better to compile from source anyway; I'm still working on fixing the upstream spec. If you install to directories you own you'd not need to involve the sysadmins at all, but you can't take advantage of pre-built binaries if your Nix store is not /nix/store

Answer (score 0):

Can you run a virtualized machine on that RedHat or somewhere else? E.g. [VirtualBox](http://VirtualBox.org) from a package like [these](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html). You could install anything from Ubuntu to something more lightweight like [Arch Linux](http://archlinux.org).

At work I do all my development in a VirtualBox Ubuntu guest. Stable, fast, convenient.